# Why this IF allow negative numbers?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know why this code accept negative numbers and how correct it.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    if (' . $_POST["product_qty"] .' < 1) {
        alert("Atleast 1");
    } else if (isNaN(x)) {
        alert("Must input numbers");
        return true;
    }
</script>';
```

Thank you

Comment: A negative number is less than `1`, so `-3 < 1` is true ?

Comment: < is the less than symbol, so "Atleast 1" displays for values which are negative, zero, etc. Use > for greater than. Edit -  it would be better to test for NaN *before* testing if it is negative, that way any strings will be caught and you won't be accidentally comparing a string from the $_POST with a number.

Comment: Why do you have `return true` when there's no function around the code?

Comment: @Mousey I think `Atleast 1` is supposed to be an error message, meaning "quantity must be at least 1"

Comment: You never set `x` before testing `isNan(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's accepting a String. Switch the `if` to this.

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['product_qty"']) && (int) $_POST['product_qty"'] < 1)
```

Comment: He's doing the `if` in Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: @Barmar isn't `echo` a PHP function?

Comment: But he's echoing a Javascript script that performs the `if`.

Comment: @cbender But he is echoing a javascript. Besides his issue is only that he mixed up `<` and `>`.

Comment: @SebastianNette I don't see that mixup. He only wants to allow quantities that are at least 1, so he displays an alert if it's less than 1.

Comment: @Barmar Oh then I'm sorry, the alert in the question is rather confusing. Since it states "atleast 1" and not "must be atleast 1".

Comment: He can make it a PHP `if` within the js that echos one of the alerts depending on the PHP `if`.

Comment: I need to implement this Javascript. The ideia is if the input is a letter or a number less than 1, send the alert